# Linq Expression is not working for Nullable string field

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expression

I am trying to create LINQ expression. The bellow 2 section of code is working for NOT NULL String fields but for NULL string fields the final expression showing "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when executing lamda.compile()

```
//code for Contains
Expression expressionSub = null;
MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });
var comparisonValue = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, typeof(StringComparison));
var actualValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
expressionSub = Expression.Call(propertyName, method, actualValue, comparisonValue);
return expressionSub;
        
//code for Equal and not equal
MethodInfo method = typeof(String).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
var dynamicExpression = Expression.Call(propertyName, method);
Expression constExp = Expression.Constant(propertyValue.ToString().ToLower());
if (operatorName == "equal")
   return Expression.Equal(dynamicExpression, constExp);
else if (operatorName == "notequal")
   return Expression.NotEqual(dynamicExpression, constExp);
else
   return null;
```

How to make above 2 section of code works for Nullable fields (for example my Email column is nullable in SQL and Name column is NOT NULL. Bellow code is working for Name but not working for Email)

Comment: What does "showing some issue" mean?

Comment: I will add more details to the question

Comment: As with any expression work, the first thing to do is work out what the equivalent C# is. Your "Contains" code is `property.Contains("actualValue", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnorecase)` -- which obviously throws an NRE when `property` is null. Likewise the second snippet calles `property.ToLower() == "constant")`, which will likewise throw an NRE if `property` is null. Work out what null-safe C# would look like, and write the equivalent expression

Comment: canton7 : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
this is the issue

Comment: Presumably that's when you invoke the compiled lambda, rather than just when you compile it?

Comment: @canton7 : can you  please give null-safe C# example for the above code

Comment: e.g. for the first snippet, you might want to write `(propery ?? "").Contains(...)`. For the second, consider `string.Equals(property, "constant", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. I'm sure you know enough C# to be able to come up with the best option yourself :)

Comment: Maybe check for nullable manually with `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()`

Comment: @Klamsi That's not relevant in the slightest -- all parameters in the questions are strings, not nullable value types

Comment: @canton7 : can u please post an answer with the above suggestion

Comment: I've got a busy morning I'm afraid -- a good answer will include the equivalent expression and a solid explanation. Feel free to post your own answer, and self-accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Expression.Coalesce` here so that it will replace possible null value with "" so the string functions will not fail.

Here is the similar code fixing the same issue:

```
string filterValue = "sa";

var filterValueExpression = Expression.Constant(filterValue);
var actualValueParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));

MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });
var comparisonExpression = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, typeof(StringComparison));
//here we replace possible null with ""
var coallesceExpression = Expression.Coalesce(actualValueParameterExpression, Expression.Constant(""));
var expressionSub = Expression.Call(coallesceExpression, method, filterValueExpression, comparisonExpression);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(expressionSub, actualValueParameterExpression);
var func = lambda.Compile();

string actualValue = null;
var result = func(actualValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will check and update here

Comment: Here we are not passing "propertyName" ?